# Как запретить ссылки на сайте?

Tags: php

Есть маленький сайт в котором есть комментарии. Как запретить ссылки в комментариях? Я знаю как запретить ссылки с `http`, но если вводят ссылки типо `google.ru`? Без `http` и `www`? Как запретить такие ссылки?

Comment: Регулярные выражения

Comment: А кто разрешает вообще вставлять ссылки в комменты? пусть выводится все как текст, а тэги искоренить!!

Answer (score 1):

> ссылки типо google.ru ? без http и www
> ? как запретить такие ссылки?

А попробуйте решить обратную задачу: как такие ссылки сделать кликабельными. Когда её решите, да так, чтобы распознавание было 1) без "ложных срабатываний" и 2) без пропусков, тогда автоматически и исходная задача решится.

Но пока решения никто не нашёл, потому что нет алгорима распознавания подобных "ссылок" с учётом пунктов 1 и 2 :) Поэтому либо бросайте эту затею и ищите другие способы борьбы со спамом, либо сформулируйте свои правила, что считать ссылками, и из них уже исходите (например: "слово, после которого идёт точка и один из TLD", etc). Первый путь, правда, безусловно лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Я извращенец :)

```
$text = 'Lorem ipsum google.com dolor http://www.google.com sit amet https://google.com/';

if(preg_match("/https:\/\/|http:\/\/|[0-9a-z_]+\.[a-z\/]{2,4}/i", $text))
{
    //echo 'Match';
    $text = preg_replace("/(https:\/\/|http:\/\/|[0-9a-z_]+\.[a-z\/]{2,4})/i", "<s>$1</s>", $text);
}

echo $text;
```